# Regex for formatting comma for decimal places and dot for thousands

Tags: regex

I need to allow following examples of inputs:

```
             n,nn

            nn,nn

           nnn,nn

         n.nnn,nn

        nn.nnn,nn

      nnn.nnn,nn

     n.nnn.nnn,nn

    nn.nnn.nnn,nn

   nnn.nnn.nnn,nn
```

I have done this:

```
(^[0-9]{1,3}(\,[0-9]{1,2})?$)

(^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})(\,[0-9]{1,2})?$)

(^[0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{3})(\.[0-9]{3})(\,[0-9]{1,2})?$)
```

and if one of these three is found than ok, but I want to make one regex instead of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may add a group `(?:\.\d{3})*` to match all the optional 3-digit groupings and add a  `*` at the beginning to allow any number of spaces (0 or more):

```
^ *\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*(?:,\d{1,2})?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sU8gG8/1)

If you also need to match numbers like `1234567,99`, you may add an alternative branch:

```
^ *(?:\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*|\d+)(?:,\d{1,2})?$
   ^                     ^^^^^
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sU8gG8/2)

Also, if you mean there can be any leading whitespace symbol, replace the literal space with a `\s` pattern.

Note that if your regex engine does not support `\d`, use `[0-9]` instead.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `*` - zero or more spaces (or `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces)
- `\d{1,3}` -  1 to 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{3})*` - zero or more sequences of `.` + 3 digits
- `(?:,\d{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `,`  -  a comma
  - `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Use '*' to signify zero or more repetitions and '\d' to express a digit. So:

```
^\d{1,3}(\.\d{1,3})*(\,\d{1,2})?$
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Now it works, so I removed down-vote. (It is however only an inferior version of Wiktors answer, with unnecessary, illogical capture groups...)